# Pre-process drupal_goto or use hook_exit() to stop redirect

Tags: 7, testing

I want to unit test some custom modules but `drupal_goto()` is causing problems by creating header errors (for example, *PHP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot send session cookie*).

Is it possible to stop `drupal_goto()` from redirecting to the destination page or somehow tap into `hook_exit()` to return `$destination`?

Answer (score 0):

This is most often caused by UTF-8 with BOM. Check your editor and change the file format if it is.

The only way to redirect in hook_exit() is another drupal_goto(). Be careful that you don't create redirection loops.

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in:

[`hook_drupal_goto_alter`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_drupal_goto_alter/7)

```
function EXAMPLE_drupal_goto_alter(&$path, &$options, &$http_response_code) {
  // example debug
  drupal_set_message('<pre>'.print_r(func_get_args(),1).'</pre>');
  drupal_set_message($_REQUEST['destination']); // maybe
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to use either of following options for redirection in this scenario.

```
$_GET['destination'] = $redirect_url;
```

or

```
$form_state['redirect'] = $redirect_url;.
```